# How to get Intellisense to show comments from .h files in .cpp files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

For simplicity here's the code

foo.h:

```
class Foo
{
    // bar 1 described
    void bar1();
    void bar2();
}
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

void Foo::bar1() {}  

void Foo::bar2()
{
    bar1();
}
```

So, when I hover over bar1() inside bar2() in file foo.cpp, I don't get a tooltip with bar1's description from foo.h. If I do it in any other file (like, some other class calls foo's bar1) then I get it, but if I do it from file foo.cpp, I don't.

When I hover over it in foo.cpp, tooltip says bar1() comes from foo.cpp and shows no tooltip, while if I hover over it from any other file, it says bar1() comes from foo.h and shows the tooltip.

So is there a fix, other than copying function description from .h file into .cpp file, and always copying it back whenever it's changed (like if I change it in .cpp I have to manually copy it to .h)

Comment: If doing serious VS development, you might want to look into Visual Assist...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177226.aspx

Comment: If doing serious VS development, you might want to look into ReSharper C++.

Comment: Hi Istrebitel, follow your description and I checked it in my side, got the same result as yours, it is by design. I tried to test it with XML Documentation, Resharper and Visual Assist, it seems only the Visual Assist can provide the tooltip like this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgy3yNqlOyc9YfAGN